# Problema com arrays no Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

Eu comecei um pequeno curso sobre deep learning com Python, mas acabei tendo um problema com arrays...
  Eu geralmente pego o código da aula e o modifico bastante antes de criar um original, mas, dessa vez, quando rodei o código estudado, ele deu um erro:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Eu tentei resolver o problema de algumas maneiras, mas não consegui. Eis o código:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


class LinearRegression:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x_data = np.random.rand(100).astype(np.float32)
        self.y_data = self.x_data * 3 + 2
        self.y_data = np.vectorize(lambda y: y + np.random.normal(loc=0.0,scale=0.1))(self.y_data)
        self.A = tf.Variable(1.0)
        self.B = tf.Variable(0.2)
        self.Y = self.A * self.x_data + self.B
        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.Y, self.y_data))
        self.optmizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
        self.train = self.optmizer.minimize(self.loss)
        self.ini = tf.initialize_all_variables()
        self.sess = tf.Session()
        self.sess.run(self.ini)
        self.train_data = []
        for step in range(0, 100):
            self.ev = self.sess.run([self.train, self.A, self.B])[1:]
            if step % 5 == 0:
                print(step, self.ev)
                self.train_data.append(self.ev)


Line = LinearRegression()
```

Comment: E qual foi a linha que deu erro?

Comment: Linha 13 :self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.Y, self.y_data))

Answer (score 1):

Na linha: `tf.square(self.Y, self.y_data)` deveria ser: `tf.square(self.Y - self.y_data)`.

Você quer calcular o erro quadrático médio e não passar `self.y_data` como nome da operação.